# Installing tesseract-ocr error on AWS Sagemaker notebook Instance

Tags: tesseract, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

When I am trying to install OCR in Notebook Instance AWS Sage-Maker using:

`! sudo yum install tesseract-ocr`

I am getting the following error:

Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, extras_suggestions, kernel-livepatch,
: langpacks, priorities, update-motd, versionlock
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/2/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
neuron                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00
286 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package tesseract-ocr available.
Error: Nothing to do

I request to please help me in this regards.